# Problema para adicionar dados em um dicionário

Tags: python, funções, dicionário

Estou tentando construir uma função para cálculo de médias de várias notas, mas ocorre erro quando tento repassar esses dados a um dicionário.

O sistema alega que a classe de dados que tento passar não é compatível, mas eu já fiz isso algumas vezes, em outros programas, e isso não costumava acontecer.

Segue o código:

```
def Media():

    Notas = {'Total:', 'Maior:', 'Menor:', 'Média:', 'Situação:'}
    
    Valor = 0
    P = 1
    Soma = 0
    c = 0
    
    while True:
        while True:
            N = str(input(f'Digite a {P}° nota: '))
            if N.isnumeric():
                Valor = float(N)
                break
            else:
                print('ERRO! Digite um valor númerico!')
        for c in range(0,1):
            Maior = Menor = Valor
            c += 1
        if Valor >= Maior:
            Notas['Maior:'] = Maior
            P += 1
            Soma += Valor
        elif Valor <= Menor:
            Notas['Menor:'] = Menor
            P += 1
            Soma += Valor
    
    
        R = str(input('Deseja inserir outro valor?' )).upper()
        if R not in 'SN':
            print('Digite uma resposta válida!')
        if R == 'N':
            break


    Media = Soma / P
    if Media < 6:
        Notas['Situação:'] = 'Tá tensa!'
    if Media > 6:
        Notas['Situação:'] = 'Ta tranquila.'
    Notas['Média:'] = Media 
    Notas['Total:'] = P

   print(Notas)


print(30 * '-')
print('CALCULADOR DE MÉDIAS DOS ALUNOS')
print(30 * '-')

print('Um momento que o sistema está iniciando...')
sleep(0.3)

Media()
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso aqui **não** é um dicionário:

```
Notas = {'Total:', 'Maior:', 'Menor:', 'Média:', 'Situação:'}
```

Na verdade você criou um [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set).

O que pode confundir é que para criar `set`'s e dicionários, usa-se chaves como delimitadores. O que distingue um do outro é o conteúdo.

Um dicionário contém pares de chave-valor. Entre a chave e o respectivo valor há um `:`, e entre cada par de chave-valor há uma vírgula. Já um `set` só possui valores, todos separados por vírgula:

```
sou_um_dicionario = {
    'chave 1' : 'valor 1', # repare nos dois-pontos separando a chave e o valor
    'chave 2' : 'valor 2'
}

print(type(sou_um_dicionario)) # <class 'dict'>

sou_um_set = {
    'valor 1', # não tem dois-pontos, somente vírgulas separandos os valores
    'valor 2'
}

print(type(sou_um_set)) # <class 'set'>
```

No caso, você criou um `set`, já que os `:` estão dentro das aspas, ou seja, eles fazem parte das strings que são os valores do `set` e não estão agindo como os separadores que ficam entre a chave e o valor.

---

Se entendi bem, o que você quer é algo assim:

```
def media():
    notas = {'maior': float('-inf'), 'menor': float('inf')}
    i = 0
    soma = 0
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                valor = float(input(f'Digite a {i + 1}° nota: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('ERRO! Digite um valor númerico!')
        if valor > notas['maior']:
            notas['maior'] = valor
        if valor < notas['menor']:
            notas['menor'] = valor
        soma += valor
        i += 1

        while True:
            opcao = input('Deseja inserir outro valor?').upper()
            if opcao not in ['S', 'N']:
                print('Digite uma resposta válida!')
            else:
                break
        if opcao == 'N':
            break

    media = soma / i
    if media < 6:
        notas['situação'] = 'Tá tensa!'
    else:
        notas['situação'] = 'Ta tranquila.'
    notas['media'] = media
    notas['total'] = i

    print(notas)


print(30 * '-')
print('CALCULADOR DE MÉDIAS DOS ALUNOS')
print(30 * '-')

print('Um momento que o sistema está iniciando...')

media()
```

`input` já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é desnecessário.

Também mudei os nomes das chaves, não vi motivo para ter `:` nelas. E eu inicio a maior nota com um valor pequeno (no caso, "infinito negativo"), assim qualquer valor que for digitado será maior que ele, e na primeira vez que testar o `if`, o `maior` será atualizado corretamente. O mesmo vale para a menor nota: se você inicia ela com zero, e só digitam valores maiores que zero, o seu programa diz que a menor nota é zero. Então eu inicio ela com um valor grande ("infinito"), assim garanto que qualquer valor digitado será menor que ela, evitando esse problema.

O seu contador `P` terminava com "1 a mais", por isso a média ficava errada.

Para ver a situação, você só testava se a média é menor ou maior que 6 (e se fosse igual a 6, ficava sem situação).

E para verificar se a nota digitada é um número, eu preferi usar um [bloco `try`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) e capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). Isso porque existem vários caracteres para os quais `isnumeric` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `float` ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/VO370W)). E como pode ser digitado qualquer coisa, o mais garantido é simplesmente tentar converter e capturar o erro.